# Sharing global variables between two projects

Tags: c#, .net

My problem is that i have `two projects` in a solution (1x `ASP`, 1x `Console`) and i want to share some data between them.

I tried it with a static class in the console-app. The problem is that the reference-class in the asp-app is a new one, and if I try to change something in this static class it is only changed in the asp-app but not in the console-app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that - but none of them should be an afterthought - you'd need to provide more context to get a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that those two projects are going to run as two different processes. The ASP.NET project is going to get run by IIS, and your console project is simply a standard .NET app.

So, you'll need some sort of communication bridge between the two. If they're on the same machine, you could use files or named pipes, and if they're on different machines, you could take advantage of the fact that one of your processes is an ASP.NET web app and use web services. You could also use a database (but that might be overkill depending on your needs).

Comment: Thank! I try it with a named pipe!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of approaches to do this, but the most common one is to use a database that is accessed by both processes.

If you could provide more context, it would make this easier to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Store it in registry and access it

Comment: On SO it is usually a good practice to show how to achieve what you are saying. Short answer might be correct in some case, but users prefer to learn why is your solution a good one and how to do it. That way, it becomes easier to understand and find. Moreover, your solution will have a better rank on search engines like Google and even SO search. Regards